# Is there a standard name (and library implementation) for a Monad that hides computation behind a constructor?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am wondering if this monad has a standard name in the Haskell ecosystem

```
data Delay a = Wait (Delay a) | Done a deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

instance Monad Delay where
  return a = Done a

  (Done a) >>= f = f a
  (Wait da) >>= f = Wait (da >>= f)
```

It is useful so that possibly non-terminating computation can be "paused".

The end goal is to combine it with `LogicT` so I can search over possibly non terminating functions.  I rolled my own implementation originally but the book-keeping was out of hand, especially since I have other monadic effects in the mix.

Comment: Looks like the resumption monad to me: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-resumption

Answer (score 10):

`Delay` looks like it is isomorphic to `Iter` from `Control.Monad.Trans.Iter` in the `free` library.

```
newtype IterT m a = IterT { runIterT :: m (Either a (IterT m a)) }

type Iter = IterT Identity

instance Monad m => Monad (IterT m) where
  return = pure
  IterT m >>= k = IterT $ m >>= either (runIterT . k) (return . Right . (>>= k))
  fail _ = never
```

Specifically, `Done a` corresponds to `IterT Identity (Left a)` and `Wait (Delay a)` to `IterT Identity (Right (IterT Identity a))`.

Comment: It's also similar  to `Stream Identity m a` from "streaming" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming.html#t:Stream

Comment: It's referred to as "Capretta's Monad" often ([this](https://www.ioc.ee/~tarmo/tday-veskisilla/uustalu-slides.pdf) presentation is linked from the `Control.Monad.Trans.Iter` page)

Comment: I ended up giving up trying to build a monad stack with `IterT` from `free` since it has an instance of `MonadPlus` that overrides the intended behavior of `LogicT`.